# Can I send attachments to a Zendesk ticket via email?

Tags: zendesk

According to the Zendesk documentation:

> Receiving attachments from customers
>
> [Zendesk accepts attachments from users sent in via the API, **email** and web form channels in your Help Center.](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203927716-Attachments-in-Zendesk#sec1)

However, I can't find any information in the documentation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understood the question, but you can just attach your document to the email you are sending in to update the ticket.